# Как отправить и получить данные в vue-resource?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

Собственно для отправки делаю так:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#id',
  data: {
    endpoint: 'send.php'
  },
  methods: {
    send: function() {
      var options = {
        params: {
          'get': 'test'
        }
      }

      this.$http.post(this.endpoint, options).then(function(responce) {
        alert(responce.data);
      }, function(error) {
        alert('error');
      })
    }
  }
})
```

А в файле php следующий код:

```
echo ($_POST['get'] == null)? 'false': $_POST['get'];
```

При отправке вылетает alert с текстом false, т.е. инфа то дошла, но дошла-то пустота.
Что тут может быть не так?

Answer (score 0):

Метод `post` имеет следующий список аргументов:

```
post(url, [body], [options])
```

По умолчанию, если вы передаете в `body` объект, то vue-resource отправит на сервер запрос с типом `application/json` и в тело запроса вложит JSON, на сервере такой запрос придется обрабатывать иначе, нежели у вас.

В вашем случае можете использовать `FormData` вот так:

```
var data = new FormData;
data.set('get', 'test');

this.$http.post(this.endpoint, data).then(function(responce) {
        alert(responce.data);
    }, function(error) {
        alert('error');
    });
```

Тогда vue-resource отправляет данные как `multipart/form-data`, и на сервере вы сможете обработать их как `$_POST['get']`.